# How to return a string as JS code that can be used to graph points?

Tags: javascript, string, return

I am generating and graphing the Fourier series of a square wave by creating a string that contains the information needed to graph the Fourier series. I need the string to be returned as usable code (`Math.sin()`, `Math.PI`, etc) so that I can use it in my graphing function. What is the best way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
//draws point to canvas
function drawPoint(x, y) {
  ctx.fillRect(x * 20, -y * 20, 1, -1);
}

// generates function to be graphed
function writeFunc(n) {
  
  // initialize vars
  func = "";
  var i = 1;
  var x = n;

  // generate string
  do {
    func += "(4*Math.sin(";
    func += x;
    func += "*x)/";
    func += x;
    func += "*Math.PI)+";
    i += 2;
    x -= 2;
  } while (i < n);


  // remove final character (+) from string
  func = func.substring(0, func.length - 1);

  return eval(new String(func));
}

// call drawPoint() for every x value in canvas
function graph() {
  for (var x = -200; x < 200; x += 0.01) {
    drawPoint(x, writeFunc(getSliderValue()));
  }

  // prints string to console
  console.log(writeFunc(getSliderValue()));
}
```